# Execute Python script with cron - doesn't work

Tags: php, python, cron

So i created a script that can send the temperature measures to database (easyPHP) and it works manually when i enter it in Putty (i use a RPi) but id doesn't work with cron (it's not sending any measures to database) , i'd like to receive the measures every 10 minutes, so i edited crontab -e (with root and pi account) to add the following:

```
10 * * * * /home/pi/1ft_www.py
```

Thank's you for help!

Comment: Any error messages? cron usually mails them, so run `mail` as the user they run as.

Comment: malformed cron line, see @nick_gabpe 's answer. You are saying you want to run the script at the 10th minute, every hour, everyday. Use `*/10` instead for interval based jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every 10 minutes `*/10 * * * *   /home/pi/1ft_www.py`

Comment: Ok; thank's you, hope it'll work now.